# How to configure JBoss to use log5j instead of log4j?

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss-3.x, log5j

How to configure JBoss to use log5j instead of log4j? 
Customers have JBoss 3.2.7.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  JBoss's logging is hard-wired to use log4j. Replacing it isn't practical.

However, there's nothing to stop your own applications from using log5j if you choose - kjust add the JAR to your applications' libraries. The logging would just be handled separately from JBoss's own logging.

Footnote: JBoss 3 is four generations behind current versions. You should *really* consider replacing it, it's beyond obsolete.